# Search over two or more table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to search over two (or three) tables

Table: persons

```
id | name | age
1  | AA   | 20
2  | BB   | 30
3  | CC   | 40
```

Table: data

```
id | person_id | item
1  | 2         | nail
2  | 2         | hammer
3  | 1         | hammer
4  | 2         | hat
```

person.id is data.person_id

So I have the following questions:

- How can I find all people who has a hammer?
- How can I find all people who have no item?
- How can I find all people who 20 and have hammer? (just add to where 'AND p.age = 20' I think now)
- How can I find all persons who has a item?

I know I can search over more tables with JOIN but I don't get it to work now.

Comment: What is the different between `How can i find all people who have no item?` and `How can i find all people with no item?` ?

Comment: there is no my mistake!

Comment: corrected to the right question, but i think i now how to do it now.. i hope!

Comment: Please don't ask all questions in a single question. Instead search for duplicate and if not found ask separately.

Comment: Please read a basic tutorial about SQL. This would be covered pretty early on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I find all people who has a hammer?

Use `INNER JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM Persons p
  JOIN data d ON p.id = d.person_id
 WHERE d.item = 'hammer';
```

> How can I find all people who have no item?

Use `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM Persons p
  LEFT JOIN data d ON p.id = d.person_id
 WHERE d.ID IS NULL;
```

> How can I find all people who 20 and have hammer?

As you have already mentioned add `AND p.age = 20` in the first query:

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM Persons p
  JOIN data d ON p.id = d.person_id
 WHERE d.item = 'hammer'
   AND p.age = 20;
```

> How can I find all persons who has a item?

Use simple `INNER JOIN` with `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
  FROM Persons p
  JOIN data d ON p.id = d.person_id;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe03b/10)

For more detail about `JOIN` have a look at this: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: ELECT DISTINCT p.*
  FROM Persons p
  JOIN data d ON p.id = d.person_id;

If there multiple rows in data for p.id is it possible to get only one row per p.id?

Comment: @user2482699 - That's why I used `DISTINCT`. Looks like you have not tested any query.

Comment: but i get not only one per p.id with DISTINCT

Comment: @user2482699 - Your first comment reads like this: *is it possible to get only one row per p.id?* and now you are saying opposite *but i get not only one per p.id with DISTINCT*. What do you actually want. Please be specific and clear.

Comment: now i get it.. i changed the syntax a bit on my query.. sorry

the p.* where the part i missed

Comment: @user2482699 - Not an issue. Just test all queries in the given SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  p.name from persons AS p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  data AS d 
ON d.person_id = p.id 
WHERE d.item LIKE "hammer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Find hammer

```
SELECT p.person_name FROM persons as p
INNER JOIN data AS d
ON d.person_id=p.person_id
WHERE d.item='hammer'
```

Find person who have no item

```
SELECT p.person_name FROM persons as p
INNER JOIN data AS d
ON d.person_id=p.person_id
WHERE d.item is null
```

Answer (score 0):

list all people who has a hammer:

```
SELECT A.name FROM persons A
JOIN data B ON B.person_id=A.id 
WHERE B.item='hammer'
```

list all people with no item :

```
SELECT A.name FROM persons A
JOIN data B ON B.person_id!=A.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is with a basic left join.
These should help you! Thanks for your question.

How can i find all people who have no item?

```
select persons.name
from persons 
left join data on persons.id=data.person_id where 
data.item='hammer';
```

How can i find all people who have no item?

```
select persons.name
from persons 
left join data on persons.id=data.person_id where 
data.item is NULL;
```